# webkitDeprecatedRTCPeerConnection, DeprecatedRTCPeerConnection, RTCPeerConnection are not supported

Tags: webrtc, p2p

I am trying to implement WebRTC. I am trying to create P2P connection using

```
var peerC = new webkitDeprecatedRTCPeerConnection("STUN stun.l.google.com:19302", onSignal);
```

Here, onSignal is:

```
// when PeerConn is created, send setup data to peer via WebSocket
function onSignal(message) {
    socket.send(message);
}

// when remote adds a stream, hand it on to the local video element
function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    remotevid.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    document.getElementById('anim').style.visibility='visible';
}

// when remote removes a stream, remove it from the local video element
function onRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
   remotevid.src = "";
}
```

But this do not work for me. Even if I use any of `webkitDeprecatedRTCPeerConnection`, `DeprecatedRTCPeerConnection`, `RTCPeerConnection`, nothing proceeds.

Some help would be really thankfull.

Comment: Please show some more of your code and what error messages you're getting, so that people might actually help.

Comment: Please add an [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Use webkitRTCPeerConnection or even better, use https://github.com/webrtc/adapter which shims RTCPeerConnection.

See also https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ for a large amount of maintained samples how to use the WebRTC API in the browser.